# Responsive svg: add inline style to `<svg>`-element

Tags: html, css, svg

For some reason my svg animation works fine in Chrome but not in Safari.
After some element inspecting in safari I found that I have to add `style="max-width:100%"` to the `<svg>`-element.

So I had this: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 825 825">`
I want to do this: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 825 825" style="max-width: 100%">`

If I do this in the element inspector from Safari this works great but if I add this to the `svg`-element Safari ignores it completely. (even after I empty out the cache)

I tried changing the `viewbox` from `0 0 825 825` to `0 0 100% 100%` but that just results in nothing being shown.

I also tried adding a class to the svg`-element but also is being ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I read up on Crossbrowser compatibility and guess what....

It solved my problem.
I duplicated every `transform` and `animation` and added `-webkit-` and `-moz-`.

Now it just works fine.

Comment: no such thing as -moz-transform. It's just transform for Firefox.

Comment: Euhm.. okay. That's my bad then. I just assumed that if there was a `-webkit-` "version" there had to be a `-moz-` "version". Thnx for that one.